# Dependency injection of EF context in WebJobApp

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-webjobs-triggered

I'm trying to create my first webjobapp that requires the use of Entity Framework.  I am trying to inject my context into the builder of the app, but I'm getting an error:
*Cannot bind parameter 'db' to type ApplicationDbContext. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding*
There are several examples on the web but the versions of the Azure WebJob appear to have changed quickly and I can't find one that works for the version I'm using.  These are the package versions I'm using:
Webjobs 3.0
EF.NET Core 7.0
Targeting .NET 7.0

Here is my code:

```
 class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddTimers();
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        });
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
         {
             configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
             configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
             configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true);
             configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true);

         });
       
       builder.ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("My full connection string"));
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
                                              });
        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        //{
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class Functions

public static void Sendemails([TimerTrigger("0 0 20 * * SUN-THU")] TimerInfo timer,
         ILogger logger,  ApplicationDbContext db)

    {
   
  
        var mylist = db.Users.ToList();
    
    }
}
```

I tried to configure the services using the following code instead of the above code. When inspecting the builder I can see that the services were added to the builder.  But inspecting the host after the call to builder.Build(), The services do not show up in the host container.

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
     .....

  builder.ConfigureServices((context, sc) =>  sc= serviceCollection);
        var host = builder.Build();
   
        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        } 
}
 .....

    private void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")))
           
        
    }
```

Project File

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <None Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference 
Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.33" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Configuration.AppSettings" Version="1.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid" Version="3.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.28.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: `ConfigureServices` is where you put *all* registrations, not something you call for each individual registration. Calling it twice probably replaces the old DI registrations with the latest one.

Comment: Did you try putting all registrations in a single `ConfigureServices` call? All .NET Core tutorials and samples show this.

Comment: I will try, but the comment on the hover over ConfigureServices states "Adds Services to the container.  This can be called multiple times and the results will be additive".  Also I commented out the 2nd call so that it is only called once and I still get the same error message.

Comment: I corrected my code as above, so that there is only one call to ConfigureServices, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Is your Application `Azure WebJob` or `Console App`. As mentioned in the document, for .NET Core Applications it is advised to go with Console Application. Refer [WebJob .NET Core code implementation section](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2019/june/writing-azure-webjobs-with-dependency-injection-net-core/).

Comment: Thank you all for my comments.  I added the project file.  The template used was a console application and I added the WebJobs package.

Comment: Remove `<None Remove="appsettings.json" />` from your `.csproj` file.

Comment: @HaimKatz "But inspecting the host after the call to builder.Build(), The services do not show up in the host container." could you please provide screenshot(hovering over host variable)

Answer (score 1):

Initially Even I got the same error.

[image]

Done few changes in `Program.cs` .

***My Program.cs:***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddTimers();
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();
            })
             .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
             {
                 configApp.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                 configApp.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_");
                 configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true);
                 configApp.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true);
             })

        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("MyDefaultConnection"));
            services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
        });


        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

If you are running locally, cross check the `local.settings.json` file once.

***My `local.settings.json` :***

```cs
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

***My `appsettings.json`:***

```cs
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "Storage Account Connection String"
  }
}
```

[image]

Also have a look at [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155903/azure-webjob-read-appsettings-json-and-inject-configuration-to-timertrigger) once.

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core).

Comment: Thank you very much Harshitha.  Unfortunately the changes have not helped.  I'm getting the same error.  When I inspect the 'host' variable after builder.build() line, I do not see the ApplicationDbcontext as one of the services registered.   I thus far am running it locally and do not have an azure storage string (I don't use it in my webjob, but I needed to add it because I was getting another error.  Do I need to set up a storage account to run it locally?

Comment: No, we don't need a Storage account for running locally.

Comment: In order for running an Azure function you need to have a storage emulator running. Azurite. And when running in Azure you will need a storage account. [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local)

Comment: To get it running even locally I had to create a storage count on azure and enter its connection string.  Even though I didn't use the storage, it still was looking for it when it registered.  I had to add the storage service otherwise I had an error with the timers.

Answer (score 0):

I do the steps from the beginning.

---

1-

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
       : base(options)
    {
       
    }
 
     
    }
```

---

2-add in appsettings.json

---

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "SqlServer": "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=SpaceManagment;User ID=sa;Password=654321;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout = 60"
},
```

---

3-

---

add in program.cs

---

```
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options
                .UseSqlServer(settings.SqlServer);
            //Tips
            // .ConfigureWarnings(warning => warning.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. Its pretty much what I tried before.